# How can I know upto which part in a NSString a UIlabel can contain?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring, uilabel

1. I have two labels side by side in the ipad with each taking half the screen.
2. I dont want to use the scrollview.
3. I just want the left label to contain the exact amount of test it can and want the remaining to go to the right label.

How can I get the length of the string that a fixed size UILabel can contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSString has a method that can return the size (in pixels) for a string with a given font.  You could use this to successively trim off characters until it fits.
[NSString sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this question with my code on how I solved pretty much the same problem: [CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange equivalent for iOS programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367051/ctframegetvisiblestringrange-equivalent-for-ios-programming)